# Restore /etc/fonts/

Tags: fonts

I accidentally deleted the entire contents of the directory /etc/fonts/. How can I restore it without having to reinstall the OS completely?
[image]

Comment: You could boot a live disk of Ubuntu and copy the contents on the live `/etc/fonts` to your `/etc/fonts`

Comment: @TonyLancer Please make that an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can boot a live disk of Ubuntu and copy the contents on the live `/etc/fonts` to your `/etc/fonts`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `dpkg -S` to list any packages on your system that would have placed files there e.g.

```
dpkg -S /etc/fonts
fonts-droid, language-selector-common, fontconfig-config: /etc/fonts
```

and then re-install those packages (note: these are from my system; yours may vary)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall fonts-droid language-selector-common fontconfig-config
```

Comment: Since we are talking about files in `/etc`, that does not work. The package system doesn't know that the files have been removed, and a reinstall won't help. You would need to first purge and then install, but due to dependencies, doing so would be tricky.